# View model is not passed when more than 150 elements should be sent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Issue related to this: [.NET ViewModel is not passed from view to controller because of specific input field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78095871/6139118)

Previously I thought the problem was with the view, however, thanks to help in the previous question I have now a clear project (so I assume that would be a reproducible minimal solution as it was pointed to me) with added elements and view model is lost, while there is more than 150 elements to pass back to POST method. There are no additional errors nowhere.

When I set `i < 100`, it works, when I set it to 150 it loses the view model.

The same issue occurs when the data comes from the database - I've tried passing the view model with sets of 50 elements (using `Take` and `Skip`), and for each of those, the view model is passed (so it's not a problem with the data itself).

Is there some sort of limit to that that I cannot find?

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Edit()
    {
        var r1 = new RecipeDTO() { Id = 1, TotalKcal = 10, TotalGL = 45, RecipeDayId = 1, MealId = 1, Name = "QQ" };
        var c1 = new List<Category>() { new Category() { Id = 1, Name = "AA" }, new Category() { Id = 2, Name = "BB" } };
        var s1 = new List<SelectedCheckboxViewModel>() { 
            new SelectedCheckboxViewModel() { CategoryId = 1, Id = 160, IsChecked = true, Name = "AA", Grams = 1, TotalKcal = 1, GL = 1.0 }, 
            new SelectedCheckboxViewModel() { CategoryId = 1, Id = 162, IsChecked = true, Name = "BB", Grams = 1, TotalKcal = 1, GL = 1.0 }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++)
        {
            s1.Add(new SelectedCheckboxViewModel() { CategoryId = 1, Id = i + 1, IsChecked = true, Name = $"AA{i}", Grams = 5, TotalKcal = 5, Amount = 0 });
        }

        var model = new RecipeViewModel() { Recipe = r1, Categories = c1, SelectedCheckboxes = s1 };
        return View("Create", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(RecipeViewModel model) 
    {
        return View("Create", model);
    }
```

RecipeDTO:

```
public class RecipeDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MealId { get; set; }
    public int RecipeDayId { get; set; }

    public List<IngredientDTO> Ingredients { get; set; } = new List<IngredientDTO>();
    public IEnumerable<Recipe_Ingredients> Recipe_Ingredients { get; set; } = new List<Recipe_Ingredients>();

    [DisplayName("Selected amount of kcals")]
    public double TotalKcal
    {
          get
          {
              double totalKcal = 0;
              Ingredients.ForEach(item =>
              {
                  totalKcal += item.Kcals;
              });
              return totalKcal;
          }
          set { }
    }

    public double TotalGL
    {
          get
          {
              double totalGL = 0;
              Ingredients.ForEach(item =>
              {
                  totalGL += item.GL;
              });
              return totalGL;
          }
          set { }
    }
}
```

Category

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

SelectedCheckboxViewModel

```
public class SelectedCheckboxViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int Grams { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; } = new Product();
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int TotalKcal
    {
        get
        {
            return Product.KcalPer100g * (Grams / 100);
        }
        set { }
    }
    public double GL
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Floor((Product.GI * (Product.CarbsPer100g * (Grams / 100)) / 100));
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

RecipeViewModel

```
public class RecipeViewModel
{
    public RecipeDTO Recipe { get; set; } = new RecipeDTO();
    public List<RecipeDTO> Recipes { get; set; } = new List<RecipeDTO>();
    public List<SelectedCheckboxViewModel> SelectedCheckboxes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public bool IsIngredientBeingSwitched { get; set; } = false;
}
```

View

```
@model RecipeViewModel

@{
    var url = Model.Recipe.Id == 0 ? Url.Action("Edit", "Home") : Url.Action("Edit", "Home");
    url = Model.IsIngredientBeingSwitched && Model.Recipe.Id != 0 ? Url.Action("Edit", "Home") : URL;
}

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="@url">
        <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Recipe.TotalKcal"></label>
            <input id="totalRecipe" asp-for="@Model.Recipe.TotalKcal" class="form-control" readonly />
            <label asp-for="@Model.Recipe.TotalGL"></label>
            <input id="totalRecipeGL" asp-for="@Model.Recipe.TotalGL" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 row">
            <input hidden asp-for="@Model.Recipe.Id" />
            <input hidden asp-for="@Model.Recipe.MealId" />
            <input hidden asp-for="@Model.Recipe.RecipeDayId" />
            <label asp-for="@Model.Recipe.Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Recipe.Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Recipe.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        @foreach (Category category in Model. Categories)
        {
            <text>
                <div class="m-2"><h3>@category.Name</h3></div>
                <div class="row">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SelectedCheckboxes.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if (Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].CategoryId == category.Id)
                        {
                            <text>
                                <div class="col-auto">
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="form-number-input" asp-for="@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].IsChecked" type="checkbox">
                                        <input hidden asp-for="@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].Id" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].IsChecked">@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].Grams">Amount: </label>
                                            <input class="form-control-sm" asp-for="@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].Grams" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].TotalKcal">Selected kcals: </label>
                                            <input class="form-control-sm total-kcal" asp-for="@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].TotalKcal" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].GL">Load: </label>
                                            <input class="form-control-sm total-gl" asp-for="@Model.SelectedCheckboxes[i].GL" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </text>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </text>
        }
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test code TotalKcal,TotalGL, and GL just like  `public double TotalGL { get; set; }`  then I set  it to 150 it can get the view model like:
[image]

Maybe the problem is about `{ get; set; }` , a limit on the length of individual form values. Defaults to 4,194,304 bytes, which is approximately 4MB. Try to set your [FormOptions.ValueLengthLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.formoptions.valuelengthlimit?view=aspnetcore-8.0) Property like below:

Add below code in your program.cs:

```
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue; // if don't set default value is: 30 MB
});
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

Comment: You are welome :)